# Join on multiple tables (multiple entries on 3rd table) to single line per user

Tags: php, mysql, join

I thought there was a way to do this, so may just be missing something...I have 3 tables with the following entry types:

> **T1:** UserID, firstName, lastName
>  **T2:** categoryID, categoryName
>   **T3:** UserID, categoryID, data

I need to find a way to pull the data so that it displays the first and last name, and the data responses for each of 5 different categoryID into a single entry per line:

> t1.firstName, t1.lastName, t3.data(for categoryID1), t3.data(for
>   categoryID2), t3.data(for categoryID3), t3.data(for categoryID4),
>   t3.data(for categoryID5)

I have the basic join:

```
SELECT t1.firstname AS First, t1.lastname AS Last, t2.data
FROM user as t1
INNER JOIN user_info_data as t2 
ON t1.id = t2.userid
INNER JOIN user_info_field as t3 
ON t2.fieldid = t3.id AND t3.id >= 3
```

which of course displays 5 lines per user. Now I need to see if I can combine each of the 5 rows from a single statement.

Comment: Check out [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) Probably what you need.

Answer (score 0):

According to the tables structure you gave, this query should do the work:

```
select
 t1.firstName, 
 t1.lastName, 
 group_concat(t3.data order by t3.category_id) as data
from t1
left join t3 on t1.UserID = t3.UserID
group by 
 t1.firstName, 
 t1.lastName
```